# Create Dynamic Gmail Labels From the Email's Subject

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-filters

Is there anyway to set up a filter that will create and apply a new label for every word in the subject line?  Something like `label:{subject}` maybe?

Obviously I wouldn't be using this for standard gmail use, I'm trying to setup gmail as a kind of note taking repository and would love to be able to just enter tags in the subject and have them automatically turned into labels.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what are you asking but it takes a bit of coding in JavaScript (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

You have to create a filter to apply a label "_toBeParsed" (or named as you pleased) to every incoming email.

The Google Apps Script should periodically search for each thread with that label, parse the subject and programmatically create a label for each word, then it must remove the original label.

Mind that in Gmail you can have a finite number of labels so you should avoid the creation of labels for common and short words.

Answer (score 2):

In your script, get the subject line of the email.  Then split that text into an array.  Then create labels for each word in that array.

Here is a great script that I've used to create nested labels:  https://ctrlq.org/code/19895-create-nested-gmail-labels

I've found using this method to create labels cuts down a LOT on the label clutter.

If you are still looking for scripts to get started, I can share code that I have cobbled together for similar operations -- but fair warning -- it's not pretty and I don't EVER claim to be an experienced coder, so my methods are probably not the best!

Answer (score 1):

I've never run across a way to create labels like you asked, but you can use gmail's search to do the same thing.  For example, you can search for:

```
subject:Monkeys
```

Which will return all emails with `Monkeys` in the subject.  You can also set up bookmarks for common searches.

Comment: True.  I could use greasemonky to setup some persistant searches to take the place of tags/labels, but I'd rather find a way to make the labels.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Gmail Labs *Quick Links* feature to create links to custom searches.

E.g. You could search for `subject:Monkeys`, then add a quick link to the page displaying the search result. After that you could display the search results for your chosen keywords with one click.

I know these are not labels but look very similar in the GUI and you would not need to use greasemonkey.

Comment: How does this help me get any closer to what I'm trying to do?  I want labels (or Custom Search links) to be created dynamically based on the words in the subject line of an email.  So if I sent myself an email with the subject line "Monkeys" it would then create a label "Monkeys".  It does not help me to have to predefine a label or a custom search because I want those links to be built based on the content of messages.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't avear that the dynamic part is such an important criteria. In that case I think your only option is greasemonkey. Depending on your use-case you might be better of with a fixed set of labels to avoid a proliferation of tags (due to typos, tags only used once, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a code for the Google Apps Script which iterates through emails and for each word in the all emails subjects create a new tag.

To make it fully work you need to just add the label for each thread which is processed.

[here](https://github.com/ProductivityTools-Learning/ProductivityTools.Learning.GAS.AutoTags) you fan find this code and additional functions which could help.

To invoke code open new **Google Apps Script** window

[image]

It is possible to create time triggers for invoking functions.

```
function createTagsFromSubject() {
var threads=GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
for(var i=0;i<threads.length;i++){
  var subject=threads[i].getMessages()[0].getSubject()
  Logger.log(subject)
  createLabels(subject)
  }
}

function createLabels(subject)
{
  createLabelSafe("AutoContainer");
  var words=subject.split(" ");
  for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++)
  {
   // Logger.log(words[i]);
    createLabel(words[i])
  }
}

function createLabel(word)
{
  word=word.replace("/","").replace("|","").replace(":","").replace("\"","").replace("(","").replace(")","")
  if (word!=null && word!="")
  {
  var finalLabel="AutoContainer/"+word;
  createLabelSafe(finalLabel)
  }
}

function createLabelSafe(word)
{
  Logger.log(word);
  if (word=="/") return
  if (word==" ") return
  
  var label=GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(word)
  if (label==null)
  {
    GmailApp.createLabel(word)
  }
}
```